# get search box on existing ng-map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i need to place search box to ng-map. I try solution from here

> https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

but i can't get it to work with my ng-map. Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sKOaZOX6FbJwDdf3Po5Z?p=preview), if someone can help me with this. I need to have two solution, one is to place marker and get coordinates (this solution working), second is search box, i have problem with this. And is there any way to restrict area for select on maps, like on maps on this [web site](http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvgis/apps4/pvest.php). sry for my bad English. Thank you

```
  [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/sKOaZOX6FbJwDdf3Po5Z?p=preview
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ng-map library](https://ngmap.github.io/) supports [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), see [places-auto-complete.js](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/0c85cb0adcf6891955d61b3de2674b28d2ff1a9b/directives/places-auto-complete.js) for a details.

Here is the list of changes to enable Place Autocomplete:

1) load `places` library like this: `<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=--KEY--&libraries=places"></script>`

2) place `input` element on page:  `<input places-auto-complete types="['geocode']" on-place-changed="placeMarker()" />`

3)implement `on-place-changed` handler, for example:

```
$scope.placeMarker = function(){
    var place = this.getPlace();  //get selected place 
    //...
};
```

Here is a [forked plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EDPs9n6MY8x45o9LsJig?p=preview) with a search box enabled

Comment: NgMap example of places auto complete: https://ngmap.github.io/#/!places-auto-complete.html

Comment: The demo has a problem with map loading.